# Improve json parse performance

Tags: android, json, parsing

I'd like to parse the json data coming from this api (taken from their example page):

https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=MSFT&outputsize=full&apikey=demo

I did build a parse method which takes ages (several seconds on my Galaxy A5) to parse the data (i know it is a lot of data to parse):

This is what i did:

```
private static List<PriceInfo> parsePriceDaily(JSONObject response, boolean onlyCurrentPrice) throws JSONException {
    long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    /* Check if this message is an Error Message = No data for symbol available.
     * If not fetch data
     * example structure
     * https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=MSFT&outputsize=full&apikey=demo
     */

    /* Get the First Object - Either Meta Data or Error Message */
    Iterator<String> it = response.keys();
    String key = it.next();
    /* Is Error? */
    if (key.contains("Error Message")) {
        throw new JSONException(response.getString(key));
    }
    /* Valid Object - process metadata */
    String timeZone = response.getJSONObject(key).getString("5. Time Zone");
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
    format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone));

    /* Process datasets */
    List<PriceInfo> result = new ArrayList<>();
    key = it.next();
    JSONObject datasets = response.getJSONObject(key); /* Time Series (Daily) */
    JSONObject dataset;
    String dateString;
    for (it = datasets.keys(); it.hasNext(); ) {
        dateString = it.next(); /* dataset */
        dataset = datasets.getJSONObject(dateString);
        Date date = new Date(0); /* standard value */
        try {
            date = format.parse(dateString);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        result.add(
                new PriceInfo(
                        date,
                        dataset.getString("1. open"),
                        dataset.getString("2. high"),
                        dataset.getString("3. low"),
                        dataset.getString("4. close"),
                        dataset.getString("5. adjusted close"),
                        dataset.getString("6. volume"),
                        dataset.getString("7. dividend amount"),
                        dataset.getString("8. split coefficient")
                )
        );
        if (onlyCurrentPrice) {
            break;
        }
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Passed time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - millis));
    return result;
}
```

What are the best improvements? Switching to another JSON library?

Comment: use Gson for json parsing

Answer (score 1):

Use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) for parsing and [JsonSchemaToPojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) for creating POJO classes .

Comment: Will try. Thanks

Comment: I am not sure if i can use the POJOs. In this JSON response the names of the objects are dates that of course are not the same for every api call. So how can i use the from JSON method if i dont know the tag names before? Trying the manual JsonReader in the meantime

Comment: Yes If json keys are dynamic then consider manually and use JSONObject keys() to iterate keys .

Comment: Gson takes longer then org.json if i parse manually ... i will look into it later for now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library from Google?