# Create a Java Model class

Tags: java, android, class

Hi I am quite new to Android development, I want to make a `model` for my `object` Task that is going to be parsed from `JSON`, I have made the same thing in `Swift` but in `Java` I am so confused with all the getters, setters and so on.

Here is a piece of my Swift code that I want to achieve in Java.

> Task.swift

```
class Task{
// from the Task
var _id: String!
var _title: String!

var id: String{
    if _id == nil{
        _id = ""
    }
    return _id
}

var title: String{
    if _title == nil{
        _title = ""
    }
    return _title
}

init(taskDict: [String: AnyObject]){
    // Task
    if let taskObject = taskDict["task"] as? [String: AnyObject]{
        if let id = taskObject["_id"] as? String{
            self._id = id
        }
        if let title = taskObject["title"] as? String{
            self._title = title
        }
   }
}
```

I would like to handle the output as above, that I check if it is `null` then return an empty `string` or 0 if `int`.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Manuel parsing will be same as in Swift you are doing.[Check this link for easy and faster parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50879670/1689926)

Comment: Seem like you simply need a model class with id and title. and make sure that non of them return `null`, right?

Comment: Hi Abed, when you're new to Android, don't waste time learning Java, go with Kotlin. The syntax is nearly the same as with swift and is still compatible with Java.

Comment: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

1: Paste your Json text.
//look over right side and do following steps.
2: Target Language: Java (choose your language)
3: Source type: JSON Schema
4: Annotation style: None
5: Mark uncheck all checkboxes except Include getters and setters
6: Click Preview

You can copy and paste moreover you can export as classes according to language.

Comment: @DenisLoh Thanks Denis, I just enrolled in a course for Kotlin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're new to android and know swift you should give kotlin a try, as its quite similar.

in Kotlin your code might look something like:

```
class Task (taskDict: HashMap<String, Any>) {

    var id: String = ""
    var title: String = ""

    init {
        // Task
        val taskObject = taskDict["task"] as HashMap<String, Any>?

        if (taskObject != null) {
            val id = taskObject["_id"] as String? ?: ""
            val title = taskObject["_object"] as String? ?: ""

            this.id = id
            this.title = title
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your java Task class would look like this:

```
 public class Task {

        private String id;
        private String title;

        public Task(String id, String title) {
            this.id = id;
            this.title = title;
        }

        public String getId() {
            if (id == null) {
                return "";
            }
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            if (title == null) {
                return "";
            }
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it could be done in Android Studio or I believe any other IDE:

1.Create a new class: (Right Click package--> New--> Java Class
2.Name your class
Create your instances:

```
private class Task {

//Instantiate your global variables
private String id;
private String title;

}
```

3.Right click in your class file--> Generate--> Getters & Setters--> Select the variables that you want getters and setters for, and that's it!

Your class should look like this:

```
public class Task {

    //Instantiate your global variables
    private String id;
    private String title;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I think since I am a beginner it is better to switch to Kotlin as others suggest.

Answer (score 0):

ideally the class should be properly encapsulated by having private data members and public getters, setters.